# Is BackboneJS and AngularJS sorting stable?

Tags: angularjs, algorithm, sorting, backbone.js

I'm thinking of using BackboneJS and AngularJS in my app. But are sorting algorithms in those frameworks stable? For example: will they preserve order of previously sorted columns within a table/collection?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about Angular but Backbone may or may not have stable sorting depending on how you use it.

All the collection sorting goes through `Backbone.Collection.prototype.sort` and if you have a look at that, [you'll see this](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L835):

```
if (_.isString(this.comparator) || this.comparator.length === 1) {
  this.models = this.sortBy(this.comparator, this);
} else {
  this.models.sort(_.bind(this.comparator, this));
}
```

If your collection's [`comparator`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) is a string (i.e. a model attribute name) or a function that expects exactly one argument, then `_.sortBy` will do the sorting and [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

> Returns a (stably) sorted copy of **list**, ...

and if you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.6.0/underscore.js#L317) you'll see that stability is enforced by using the element index as a secondary sort key.

If the collection's `comparator` can't be used with `_.sortBy` then [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is used and that doesn't guarantee stability.

Comment: Good answer. One need to be careful with Backbone to maintain stability. Angular has `orderBy` filer but they don't write anything about stability.

Comment: I suppose you could override `Collection#sort` to allow for the index trick with two-argument `comparator`s. You might want to check Angular to see how `orderBy` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular (as of v1.3) if you are using the `orderBy` filter in an `ng-repeat` it will sort stably with respect to the *original list* as opposed to the currently sorted list. This can lead to unexpected results, but it's not necessarily an unstable sort.

For example, if you have an app with a simple controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('SortingCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        name: 'A',
        value1: 5,
        value2: 10,
        value3: 0
      }, {
        name: 'B',
        value1: 2,
        value2: 15,
        value3: 0
      }, {
        name: 'C',
        value1: 6,
        value2: 12,
        value3: 0
      }
    ];

    $scope.sort = {
      predicate: 'name'
    };

  });
```

And a simple view:

```
<body ng-controller="SortingCtrl">

  <select ng-model="sort.predicate">
    <option>name</option>
    <option>value1</option>
    <option>value2</option>
    <option>value3</option>
  </select>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>value1</th>
      <th>value2</th>
      <th>value3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sort.predicate">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.value1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.value2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.value3 }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

If you sort first by value1 or value2, you'll get the results you expect.  However, what would you expect if you were to *then* choose value3?  Well, the values are all 0, so I would expect the order of the table to remain unchanged.  In fact, it will resort in the original order A, B, C.

This doesn't mean that Angular's `orderBy` filter is not a stable sort, but it can lead to some unexpected results you should be aware of.  Here's a plunk to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/rwrMQXSsB9wU3KBnWZBk?p=preview